# Get 4th Thursday of November in Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to add write a script which checks for file arrivals and I want to exclude some days(2nd January, 26th December, Each Monday, Day after Thanksgiving Day) I have got checks for all except Thanksgiving which is a bit tricky to do checks for a day after 4th thursday of november every year in the IF condition.

```
CURRENT_DATE=$(TZ=America/New_York date +%Y%m%d)
echo $CURRENT_DATE

Year=$(TZ=America/New_York date +%Y)
echo $Year

MD=$(TZ=America/New_York date +%m%d)
echo $MD

if [ "$DAY" == "Mon" ] || [ "$MD" == "0102" ] || [ "$MD" == "1226" ];
then
   echo "Files Not Expected - No Alerts Raised"
else
   echo "Files Expected"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ncal` and `awk` to get the fourth Thursday, then add one:

```
$ ncal -m 11  
    November 2018     
Mo     5 12 19 26   
Tu     6 13 20 27   
We     7 14 21 28   
Th  1  8 15 22 29   
Fr  2  9 16 23 30   
Sa  3 10 17 24      
Su  4 11 18 25      
$ ncal -m 11  | awk '/^Th/{print $5+1}'
23
```

Comment: How do we do for fourth thursday?

Comment: Adding one just gives you the Friday following whatever Thursday you find (and only gives you a valid day in November because Nov 30 can't be the 4th Thursday.)

Comment: @dawg He wants the *4th* Thursday (American Thanksgiving).

Comment: Oh! No, my mistake, I see it is the day after the 4th Thursday in November.

Comment: @JamesBrown: *Won't this fail if Nov 1st is a Friday?* Don't think so. Nov 1, 2019 falls on Friday. Try `ncal 11 2019  | awk '/^Th/{print $5+1}'`

Comment: I stand corrected. For my defence I gotta say that it is really early morning over here... :D

Comment: Coffee my friend. ;-)

Comment: This is the best solution @dawg. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

4th Thursday could be 22nd to 28th. The following Friday, then, is 23rd to 29th.

```
for d in {23..29}
do if [[ Fri == $(date -d 11/$d +%a) ]]
   then echo $d; break;
   fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a trick you can use here: the first [any weekday] of the month will always be between the 1st and 7th, the second between the 8th and 14th, the third between the 15th and 21st... and the fourth between the 22nd and 28th. So Thanksgiving will always fall on the Thursday between November 22nd and 28th, and the day after Thanksgiving will fall on the Friday between November 23rd and 29th. Thus, you can check it like this:

```
if [ "$DAY" = "Mon" ] || [ "$MD" = "0102" ] || [ "$MD" = "1226" ] || \
    { [ "$DAY" = "Fri" ] && [ "$MD" \> "1121" ] && [ "$MD" \< "1130" ]; }; then
```

Notes:

- I'm assuming `$DAY` is set to something like `$(TZ=America/New_York date +%a)`. I'd recommend switching to use numeric days of the week, so it'll work in non-English locales.
- I'd also recommend switching to lower- or mixed-case variable names. There are a lot of all-caps variables with special meanings, and accidentally reusing them can cause weird results.
- I used `\> "1121"` and `\< "1130"` instead of `\>= "1122"` and `\<= "1130"` because `[ ]` doesn't have `<=` and `>=` operators.
- I use `{ ;}` to logically group the day-after-Thanksgiving test; you could use `( )` instead, but that creates an unnecessary subshell.
- Finally, I replaced the `==` tests with `=` -- single equal is standard in this context; bash understands double-equal as a synonym, but if you're counting on bash it'd be better to use `[[ ]]` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If your `date` command supports `-d` option, try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# caclulate the day after the 4th Thursday of the given year

export LC_TIME=C
month=11
year=$(date +%Y)    # assign to the year as "2018"
firstdayofweek=$(date -d "${year}-${month}-1" +%w)
# calculates the day of week of the 1st day between 0 and 6
# where 0=Sun, 1=Mon, ...

thu1=$(( (11 - $firstdayofweek) % 7 + 1 ))
# calculates the day of month of the 1st Thursday

thu4=$(( $thu1 + 21 ))
# the day of the 4th Thursday

dayAfterThanksGiving=$(( $thu4 + 1 ))
echo "$dayAfterThanksGiving"
```

Then the output is 23.

Comment: Can't we do with a dynamic year, I actually thought of something similar but year changes must be taken in automatically

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the issue. How would you like to assign the `year`? It can be done automatically, manually or whatever.

Comment: `date` is the top 3 of the most frustrating Unix utilities to me. Every OS has a radically different interface.

Answer (score 0):

Using @GordonDavisson's observation that *Thanksgiving will fall on the Friday between November 23rd and 29th* and using Bash's `=~` regex:

```
if [ "$DAY" == "Mon" ] || [ "$MD" == "0102" ] || [ "$MD" == "1226" ] ||  # split to
   [ "$DAY" == "Fri" ] && [[ "$MD" =~ 112[3-9] ]]                        # emphasize
then
    echo "Files Not Expected - No Alerts Raised"
else
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier, the 4th Thursday lays between 22 and 28. With some modulo arithmetic, you can get

```
$ date -d "2019-11-22 + $(( (4 + 7 -  $(date -d '2019-11-22' +%w))%7)) days"
```